# Raspberry-pi docker error: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've installed docker in rapsbian according to the official instructions (i.e., running `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`) but I'm not able to run the hello-world example (I've also tried other examples without success). This is the error I'm getting:

```
pi@raspberrypi2:~ $ docker run hello-world
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

My environment is Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) and Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22.

Any hint about the problem or possible directions to solve the problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Raspberries use ARM and not x86_64 processors. You can only run images created for that architecture. Try searching for ARM or ARMv7 on docker hub. There is a [Debian](https://hub.docker.com/r/armv7/armhf-debian/) image for ARM I know of but there must be others as well.

The underlying issue is that the binary format used by ARM is not compatible with x86_64, which is the architecture used by most desktop and server systems.

Comment: You are right, thanks! In this link (https://hub.docker.com/u/armhf/) there are some useful official (in experimental stage currently) images for ARM architectures, including the `hello-world` example.

Comment: As of November 2019 Docker has facilities for building for building for multiple architectures at the same time: https://mirailabs.io/blog/multiarch-docker-with-buildx/

Answer (score 4):

Add to the beginning of your file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It works for me

Comment: @Kairat Koibagarov What do you mean add to beginning of your file... what file?

Comment: You may have put a script file as CMD in your dockerfile. If so, you can add this at the beginning of this script file to tell your system how to read it (here it is a shell script)