# **kiwi-tcms** docker containers not starting on Raspberry

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, kiwi-tcms

**Problem description:**

I have followed the step-by-step described on this site: https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html

After running `docker-compose up -d`, the containers are created and started but they stay in a restart-loop. Here is `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
ddf39b7a13d0        kiwitcms/kiwi:latest   "/bin/sh -c /httpd-f…"   5 days ago          Restarting (1) 39 seconds ago                       kiwi_web
27cb40760c4a        centos/mariadb         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 days ago          Restarting (1) 27 seconds ago                       kiwi_db
```

Note that this containers were created 5 days ago and they keep restarting after a few seconds.

I tried `docker run -ti kiwitcms/kiwi:latest` instead of `docker-compose up -d`, this is what i got:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

**System description**

```
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3 b+
Distributor ID: Raspbian 
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)
Release:    9.8
Codename:   stretch
```

Any ideas? I'm new to both docker and kiwi. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is probably because of the ARM architecture the RPi has, see this: [Raspberry-pi docker error: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused “exec format error”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885538/raspberry-pi-docker-error-standard-init-linux-go178-exec-user-process-caused)

Comment: Yeah, i should have guessed. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Thanks @tgogos !

Comment: > Yeah, i should have guessed. Can anyone confirm this?  If you look at the image details you will see it says architecture amd64: https://hub.docker.com/layers/kiwitcms/kiwi/latest/images/sha256-fbfd719ca4ab560149f46817094211bf0214fdc0a02c6e3b18ea582c493a156e

Comment: @AlexanderTodorov Thank you so much. Next time, i'll check the image details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this an official answer the problem was that the underlying OS was arm while the docker image architecture was amd64 so not compatible.